# Hazelcast increased Context Switching

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

[image]

Hazelcast in Embedded mode is increasing Context Switching by approximately 46%,  Is this expected? 
Is there anyway to control or configure the same?

Answer (score 0):

Except the 2 health monitor threads, rest are Hazelcast internal threads and it is not recommended to change anything there unless they are having a drastically negative affect on performance.

What is shown in the attached picture is the total time taken by the threads. 8 threads is not a lot of context switching. You will need to provide more information on how this impacts your application.

If you do not want health monitoring and diagnostics, you can disable it.

Check out https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.5/manual/html-single/index.html#threading-model for info on other threads.